# What is the purpose of parsing arguments to functions?

Tags: linux, bash

If I do

```
#!/bin/bash

a=2
func() {
    echo $a
    echo $b
}

b=3
func $b
```

then it prints `2\n3`, where I would have expected only `3`.

**Question**

When globals are available inside functions. What is the purpose then of parsing arguments to functions in BASH?

Comment: Variables declared outside a function will always be global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass arguments to functions so that they can work on different parameter values.

Your code isn't using the passed arguments, it's using the global variables. Consider instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=2
b=3

func() {
  echo $1
}

func ${a}
func ${b}
```

Yields:

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Bash does not work like this. 
You didn't take any argument inside the function. Instead, you just initialized two global vars that you echoed later in you function.

In order to do what you need you should do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=2
func() {
    # first argument
    echo $1
    # second argument
    echo $2
}

b=3
func $b
func $a $b
```

Output:

```
3

2
3
```